# Spring 4 dependency injection for abstract generic classes do not work

Tags: java, spring, generics, dependency-injection, autowired

I have base classes `X` and `Y`, which have multiple implementations. However, there is only one implementation for each parameterized type, therefore the `@Autowired` should be able to figure out which subclass is needed.

This actually works before adding the second parameter `U` to the base classes `X` and `Y` (and thus to all their subclasses). But after adding that, here is the error during Spring initialization:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'myApp': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'x1'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'xImpl1': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'y'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'test.Y>'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

The code in github (maven project): https://github.com/kevincentius/spring-di-abstract-generic-problem/tree/master/spring-test

The abstract generic classes `X<T, U>` and `Y<T, U>` reference each other:

```
@Component
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public abstract class X<T, U> {

    protected T t;
    protected U u;

    @Autowired
    protected Y<T, X<T, U>> y; // error when initializing xImpl1

    // ...

}
```

class `Y` knows the implementing class `V` (e.g. `XImpl1`). As opposed to `X` which only knows the abstract class `Y`, but not its implementing type (e.g. `YImpl1`).

```
@Component
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public abstract class Y<T, V extends X<T, ?>> {

    protected T t;
    protected V v;

    // ...

}
```

A pojo class:

```
public class A {
    // pojo
}
```

A simple interface:

```
public interface B {
    // ...
}
```

This is just one of the subclasses of `X`, but this is the ONLY subclass of `X` with parameterized types `A` and `B` (i.e. the only subclass of `X<A, B>`):

```
@Component
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class XImpl1 extends X<A, B> {
    // ...
}
```

Same like above - the only implementation of `Y<A, B>`. Although there are other implementations of `Y` with different parameterized types.

```
@Component
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class YImpl1 extends Y<A, XImpl1> {
    // ...
}
```

Finally use the implementations:

```
@Component
public class MyApp {
    @Autowired
    XImpl1 x1; // error
}
```

Might be useful information:

If I make the classes X and Y to be non abstract, the initialization error is gone, but then even if XImpl1 overrides a method on X, this does not apply after dependency injection! i.e. in MyApp, calling x1.something() does not actually call the method of XImpl1, but instead the something() method of the X class.

I might have made some mistakes here, I'd be delighted if anyone can point something out. But otherwise, seems like Spring still has some limitations?